# Why does Twitter redefine window.setTimeout and window.setInterval?

Tags: javascript, twitter, settimeout, setinterval

I was studying the Twitter source code, and I came across the following snippet:

```
   window.setTimeout=window.setTimeout;window.setInterval=window.setInterval;
```

Why does Twitter redefine these functions?

Edit:
To see the code, go to any twitter user page, open the source of the page, and you will see that snippet in the second block of javascript.

Comment: What's the context? I don't think this question is answerable without a link to the full code.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a technique to replace `setTimeout` and `setInterval` functions globally in a cross-browser fashion.

> `window.setTimeout`, when used as an lvalue (on the left side of the
>   assignment), does not walk the prototype chain, but on the right side,
>   it does. So this will always pull a property out of the prototype
>   chain and put it right on the object.

See http://www.adequatelygood.com/2011/4/Replacing-setTimeout-Globally.

Comment: I am a big fan of this answer.

Comment: In case you don't want to read the article: The crucial part is that this is used to work around a bug in IE. Specifically, the assignment `setTimeout = ...;` throws an exception unless you use the trick above. Same for `setInterval` and others.