# Objects in anonymous function

Tags: javascript, oop, anonymous-function

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does Twitter redefine window.setTimeout and window.setInterval?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8044433/why-does-twitter-redefine-window-settimeout-and-window-setinterval)

I saw a code like that

```
   window.a = 5;
   (function() { window.a = window.a; })();
```

why should they do it like that? Why not just do

```
  (function() { window.a = 5; })();
```

more example

```
    (function() { window.setInterval = window.setInterval; })();
```

Isn't it the same principle like above?

Comment: Yes i saw the setinterval code

Comment: Where did you see this? Please link or post the whole file. The current snippet is just sense- and useless.

Comment: Then there's no difference. You could do it interchangeably.

Comment: Seems like this is a valid concept? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8044433/why-does-twitter-redefine-window-settimeout-and-window-setinterval

Comment: @RussellDias Whoa. Ok, that sort of almost makes sense.  I've never seen this before. That's a bizarre JS WTF right there.

Comment: Yes russell thats what I saw but I dont find it anymore in twitter

Comment: @user1801625: Well, your answer is right there :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is <strike>no</strike> very little sense and use in doing that. I wouldn't know what more to answer.

As @RussellDias pointed out in a comment, there might be an pretty edgy edge case for IE7+8 (maybe also below) where it *might be reasonable* to re-assign native methods to itself.

See http://adequatelygood.com/2011/4/Replacing-setTimeout-Globally

---

Comment: Have a look at: http://www.adequatelygood.com/2011/4/Replacing-setTimeout-Globally

Comment: @RussellDias: Interesting article. Its obv against any "good practice" pattern and looks quite academic, but still, I was wrong in saying there is "*no*" sense at all.

Answer (score 0):

As you say, it doesn't have sense. you can just do:

```
window.a = 5;
```

The other ones are equivalent.

Cheers